# How to separately group values together based on column value in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda dataframe. I need to group based on a column value.

```
State   Dates      Sales_Amt
A       1/1/2023     123
A       2/1/2023     123
A       3/1/2023     321
A       4/1/2023     321
A       5/1/2023     123
A       6/1/2023     123
A       7/1/2023     123
B       1/1/2023     456
B       2/1/2023     456
B       3/1/2023     456
B       4/1/2023     789
B       5/1/2023     789
B       6/1/2023     789
B       7/1/2023     123
B       8/1/2023     123
```

However, if there's next group value has same value as previous grouping value it need to separate out as new group.

```
State   Start_Dates  End_Dates   Sales_Amt
A       1/1/2023     2/1/2023       123
A       3/1/2023     4/1/2023       321
A       5/1/2023     7/1/2023       123 
B       1/1/2023     3/1/2023       456
B       4/1/2023     6/1/2023       789
B       7/1/2023     8/1/2023       123
```

How can get to the result above?

I had tried the codes below but it only works for group B but not group A

```
df = (df.groupby(['State','Sales_Amt'],group_keys=True)
        .agg(Start_Dates=('Dates', np.min), 
             End_Dates=('Dates', np.max))
        .sort_values(['State','Start_Dates','End_Dates'],ascending=True)
        .reset_index()
     )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an extra grouper to pool the consecutive values:

```
# ensure datetime
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])

# add a grouper for consecutive values
group = (df['Sales_Amt'].ne(df.groupby('State')['Sales_Amt'].shift())
         .cumsum().rename('g')
        )

# groupby your columns + this grouper
out = (df.groupby(['State', 'Sales_Amt', group], group_keys=True)
         .agg(Start_Dates=('Dates', np.min), 
              End_Dates=('Dates', np.max))
         .sort_values(['State','Start_Dates','End_Dates'],ascending=True)
         .reset_index()
         .drop(columns='g') # remove the extra grouper (optional)
      )
```

Output:

```
  State  Sales_Amt Start_Dates  End_Dates
0     A        123  2023-01-01 2023-02-01
1     A        321  2023-03-01 2023-04-01
2     A        123  2023-05-01 2023-07-01
3     B        456  2023-01-01 2023-03-01
4     B        789  2023-04-01 2023-06-01
5     B        123  2023-07-01 2023-08-01
```